# findContour() detect unintended internal edges and calculates area wierd for them OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm not sure what is going on here but when I use the `findContours()` function using the `cv2.RETER_EXTERNAL` on this image:

[image: Edges]

it still seem to detect inside contours and calculates the area of them weirdly which prevents me from filtering the unwanted contours....

Any clue to why is that?

Here is the original and dialated tresh images:

[image: Original]

[image: dialated]
here's the code so far:

```
import cv2
import PIL
import numpy as np
import imutils
imgAddr = "ADisplay2.jpg"

cropX = 20
cropY = 200
cropAngle = 2

CropIndex = (cropX, cropY, cropAngle)

img = cv2.imread(imgAddr)
cv2.imshow("original image",img)



(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
(cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

# rotate our image by 45 degrees
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -1.2, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h))
#cv2.imshow("Rotated by 45 Degrees", rotated)

cropedImg = rotated[300:700, 100:1500]

# grab the dimensions of the image and calculate the center of the image


#cv2.imshow("croped img", cropedImg)

grayImg = cv2.cvtColor(cropedImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv2.imshow("gray scale image", grayImg)

blurredImg = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayImg, (9, 9), 0)
cv2.imshow("Blurred_Img", blurredImg)

(T, threshInvImg) = cv2.threshold(blurredImg, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("ThresholdInvF.jpg", threshInvImg)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,19))
#opening = cv2.morphologyEx(threshInvImg, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
#cv2.imshow("openingImg", opening)

dialeteImg = cv2.morphologyEx(threshInvImg, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
cv2.imshow("erodeImg", dialeteImg)

cannyImg =  cv2.Canny(dialeteImg, 100,200)
cv2.imshow("Canny_img", cannyImg)

hierarchy,cntsImg,_ = cv2.findContours(cannyImg,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#print("Img cnts: {}".format(cntsImg))
#print("Img hierarchy: {}".format(hierarchy))


txtOffset = (25, 50)

for cntIdx, cnt in enumerate(cntsImg):
    cntArea = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    print("Area of contour #{} = {}".format(cntIdx, cntArea))
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(cropedImg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    txtIdxPos = [x,y]
    txtPos = ((txtIdxPos[0] + txtOffset[0]), (txtIdxPos[1] + txtOffset[1]))
    cv2.putText(cropedImg, "#{}".format(cntIdx), txtPos, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.25, (0, 0, 255), 4)





cv2.imshow("drawCntsImg.jpg", cropedImg)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks for helping :D

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You you want a single contour around each digit?

Comment: Yes and I'd like to eliminate the child contours on the way because cv2.RETER_EXTERNAL doesn't seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to only use them if they're within a certain size. For this you could use [`contourArea()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea). It seems you already compute this anyhow.

For example:

```
for cntIdx, cnt in enumerate(cntsImg):
    cntArea = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    #########################

    # Skip iteration if area is too big or small to filter out non-digits
    if cntArea < 50 or cntArea > 100: continue   # Need to fiddle with these values

    #########################

    print("Area of contour #{} = {}".format(cntIdx, cntArea))
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(cropedImg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    txtIdxPos = [x,y]
    txtPos = ((txtIdxPos[0] + txtOffset[0]), (txtIdxPos[1] + txtOffset[1]))
    cv2.putText(cropedImg, "#{}".format(cntIdx), txtPos, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1.25, (0, 0, 255), 4)
```

You are already printing out each contour's area. You could use that to get an idea of what sizes to let through.

If the size digits might vary between images it could still be a problem. For that you could, for example, calculate the average contour area, which should be very close to the typical digit area. Then say that each contour should be at least *this* close to the average area.

**Note:** Just remember to make the minimum area large enough to let a `1` through.

---

**Update:**

If you want to rather use aspect ratio, then it's easy to change your formula, as you already calculate the height and width.

```
# If height is smaller than 1.5*w or larger than 2.5*w, then skip
if not 1.5 < h/w < 2.5: continue  # Need to fiddle with these values
```

You could even use this to calculate the area. It has a chance as being different from `contourArea`. For example:

```
cntArea = w*h
```

Comment: Still isn't there any way to eliminate those internal contours? sins I'd like to more filter those with aspect ratio more and make it as universal as possible....

Comment: I updated my answer to rather use aspect ratio. You should also remember SO will rarely give plug-and-play answers. You will always need to fit it into your code yourself, and fix weird edge cases like `#7`.

Comment: The `cntArea < 50` should eliminate the internal contours. Or `not 1.5 < h/w`. You must choose the solution we give that works best for you. Although I'm not sure why you still get internal contours.